# Python - Website Log In - Scraping CSRF Token failed

Tags: html, python-3.x, missing-data, login-script, csrf-token

I am new here and new at programming. I am trying to log in the 
**URL**='https://www.esselunga.it/area-utenti/applicationCheck?AppName=esselungaEcommerce&daru=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.esselungaacasa.it%3A443%2Fecommerce%2Fnav%2Fauth%2Fsupermercato%2Fhome.html%3F&loginType=light'.

When I inspect the webpage I clearly see the csrf_token in the HTML ('name'='X-CSRF-TOKEN') and its value; **however** when I extract it with BeautifulSoup it is not available. I checked the content (requests.session().get(url).content) the csrf_token lines *disappeared*, same in the 'View Page Source'.

Is it possible to retrieve the CSRF still, or is there anyway to log in without it?

thanks!

---

```
import requests                                                                       
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                                                                                               

## Here below the data collected from the Network source view, once i logged in. Form Data section:

login_data= {'username':'xxxx',  # <- instead of xxx put your username
            'password':'xxxx',   # <- instead of xxx put your psswrd               
            'daru':'xxx',        # <- data taken from the FORM DATA 
            'dare':'xxxx',       # <- data taken from the FORM DATA 
            'appName': 'xxx'}    # <- data taken from the FORM DATA 

with requests.Session() as s:                                                          
    login_url="xxx"                 #<- the URL is above in the comment
    result = s.get(login_url)    
    print (result.content)          # here you can see the X-CSRF-TOKEN is not extracted.                                                               
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content,'html5lib')                                         
    p = soup.find('input', attrs={'name':'X-CSRF-TOKEN'})['value']    # I can see it in the inspection tab                      
    print(p)         # csrf token is not in the content, neither when i check the 'view page source'. But in the inspection I see it!


    ## I am stuck at the above line. The following would be:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    login_data['X-CSRF-TOKEN']) = p                                                   
    r = s.post(login_url,data=login_data)                                                   
    print(r.content)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the page in your broswer with javascript disabled? do you see the username pop up when java script is disabled or can you find the CSRF token when you inspect the page with java script diabled? requests and beautiful soup will only see the code that you can see with view source, it wont see any javascript updates to the page which might add, modify or delete content in the page. Likely scenario is that the username login form and CSRF token are populated by a JS event that happens after the page source so it wont be visable to requests or beautiful soup

Comment: thanks for your reply, i checked and the javascript is allowed. do you know any module that can overcome this issue?

Comment: I think you missed my point. If you turn off java script in your broswer and load the page, you will see the CSRF token doesnt exist and the login box doesnt pop up. Meaning thats exacly how requests will see it. I.E requests will not see the CSRF because its loaded by a JS event.

Comment: You can use selenium